# PHP multiple array sorting method

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, sorting

If I have this array:

```
//$myarray
Array (
    [0] => Array (
        [b163cb25371a1b7c550d8f69fe211cc8] => Array (
            [unique_key]        => 14f74cf38563b889386beeec511033e2
            [thwepof_options]   => Array (
                [order_date] => Array (
                    [name] => order_date
                    [value] => 1
                    [label] => Szállítási nap
                    [options] =>
                )
            )
        )
    )
 )
```

How can I write a sorting method which sort the values by `order_date [value]`

I've tried first to get the array column like this but didn't got any return value:

```
<?php
$days = array_column($myarray[0]['thwepof_options'], 'value', 'order_date');
?>
```

Comment: What is `Szállítási nap` ?

Comment: @SherylHohman It is the label of the order_date input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are skipping the 2nd level key.
Here's a working version of your code:

```
<?php
$myarray = Array (
    0 => Array (
        'b163cb25371a1b7c550d8f69fe211cc8' => Array (
            'unique_key'        => '14f74cf38563b889386beeec511033e2',
            'thwepof_options'   => Array (
                'order_date' => Array (
                    'name' => 'order_date',
                    'value' => 1,
                    'label' => 'Szállítási nap',
                    'options' => null
                )
            )
        )
    )
 );

$days = array_column($myarray[0]['b163cb25371a1b7c550d8f69fe211cc8']['thwepof_options'], 'value', 'order_date');

print_r($days);
```

Also, this thing looks to me like it would make more sense as an object.